# Not able to skip scenarios in Jbehave with JunitStory

Tags: bdd, jbehave

I have been following lot of posts & threads based on which have integrated 
the logic to skip scenarios. Still not able to get it working successfully.
When i put the 
"configuredEmbedder().useMetaFilters(Arrays.asList("-skip"));"
OR 
"configuredEmbedder().useMetaFilters(Arrays.asList("+skip"));"
in the storyrunner,java file, none of the scenarios are executed.
And when I remove the line, all the scenarios are executed.
My .story file has "Meta   skip" in 2 of the 4 scenarios. 
Can someone please look into this & let me know what I may have missed.

Below is the class where all the configs reside
public class SampleStory extends JUnitStory {

```
public SampleStory() {
    configuredEmbedder().embedderControls()
            .doGenerateViewAfterStories(true)
            .doIgnoreFailureInStories(false).doIgnoreFailureInView(true)
            .useStoryTimeoutInSecs(60);

    configuredEmbedder().useMetaFilters(Arrays.asList("+skip"));

    /* removeStartIgnoreCase */
    // StringUtils.removeStartIgnoreCase("","");
}

@Override
public Configuration configuration() {
    Configuration configuration = new MostUsefulConfiguration();

    Properties viewResources = new Properties();
    viewResources.put("decorateNonHtml", "true");
    viewResources.put("reports", "ftl/jbehave-reports-with-totals.ftl");

    // Where to find the stories
    StoryLoader storyLoader;

    storyLoader = new LoadFromRelativeFile(
            CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(this.getClass()));

    configuration.useStoryLoader(storyLoader);

    StoryReporterBuilder storyReporterBuilder;
    storyReporterBuilder = new StoryReporterBuilder();

    // storyReporterBuilder.withDefaultFormats();
    storyReporterBuilder.withDefaultFormats();
    // storyReporterBuilder.withViewResources(viewResources).withFormats(CONSOLE,
    // TXT, HTML, XML);
    // storyReporterBuilder.withFormats();

    // CONSOLE reporting
    configuration.useStoryReporterBuilder(storyReporterBuilder);

    return configuration;
}

/*
 * @Override public Embedder configuredEmbedder() {
 * super.configuredEmbedder().useMetaFilters(Arrays.asList("-skip"));
 * 
 * 
 * return super.configuredEmbedder(); }
 */

@Override
public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {
    return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(), new SampleSteps());
```

### }

```
Snenairo.story 
Scenario:  This is scenario 1
Given I say hello
When I say bye
Then whatever

Scenario:  This is scenario 2
Meta : @skip
Given I say ello
When I say ye
Then whatever
```

---

There is another class where all the binding menthods for g/w/t exists.

Answer (score 2):

Got an reply from the group of the devs of jbehave - there was a syntax error 
i did 
    meta: @skip
but it should have been
    meta : @skip

Answer (score 1):

I used `@ignore` like this in my jbehave scenario and it worked.

```
Scenario: Employee1 - Delete Employees
Meta:
@ignore
```